# how can I refresh a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

A complete beginner to WPF so please bear with.

Added a Datasource 'ActionResult' and displays on screen through a datagrid. Add a button 'Update' which when clicked will refresh the datagrid, updating any changes made manually to the database table.

```
//in MainWIndow.xaml.cs:
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   actionResultsDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

i've stepped through this and it just gives the details of the current records in the datagrid, not the updates.

Do I need to do some sort of data binding? please advise. thanks

From research I need some sort of ObservableCollection and property changes. Is this necessary. Can I not just refresh the view?

**EDIT**
Also tried playing with the following:

```
ActionResult.CreateActionResult(100, "todo", "sales.dat",
                        System.DateTime.Now, "success", "no reason");

actionResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
actionResultsDataGrid.UpdateLayout();

Model1.AcceptChanges();
DataGrid.Items.Refresh();
actionResultsDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
actionResultsDataGrid.UpdateLayout();

actionResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
actionResultsDataGrid.ItemSource = actionResultsDataGrid;

BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(myTextBox, 
                        TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

**My XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="actionResultsViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:ActionResult, CreateList=True}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource actionResultsViewSource}">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="actionResultsDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Margin="0,0,0,85">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Header="Id" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="actionColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Action}" Header="Action" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="fileColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=File}" Header="File" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="timeStampColumn" Header="Time Stamp" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=TimeStamp, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="resultColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Result}" Header="Result" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="reasonColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Reason}" Header="Reason" Width="SizeToHeader" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="388,253,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you binding the grid in XAML?  What does the property or data structure look like that you're assigning to the grid?  You should definitely be able to either update the data source directly, or assign new one; reassigning the same object to ItemsSource would likely not do anything.

Comment: yeah binding the grid in XAML please see update

Comment: How are you trying to update the data?  I don't see a problem in the XAML.  Are you directly updating `actionResultsViewSource`?

Comment: The database will be updated manually from SQL server management studio. Then hopefully when 'update' is clicked the datagrid will simply refresh? can you advise me how to go about this please? thanks

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is a way to go. Avoid hacks of setting `ItemsSource` to null and re-set.

Comment: ok thanks I shall try this.

Comment: please see my attempt at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662324/using-inotifypropertychanged-to-refresh-a-databound-datagrid