# Using INotifyPropertyChanged to refresh a databound datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have created a databound datagrid in WPF: 'ActionResults', when I run the application it shows the contents of the database table.

The I.T dept. are going to manually update the 'ActionResult' table in SQL server management studio. If any changes are made to the table, they will display in the datagrid only after I restart the application. I would like to add an 'Update' button which will re-fresh the datagrid, displaying any changes made to the table.

I was previously trying to do a hack with something like

```
actionResultsDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

but decided to go with the ObservableCollection. So I have been following the http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CKB44Mc4Q0 tutorial the only problem is he manually creates his records, where I will be using the db. Here is where I am so far:

```
//XAML
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="actionResultsViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:ActionResult, CreateList=True}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource actionResultsViewSource}">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="actionResultsDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Margin="0,0,0,85">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Header="Id" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="actionColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Action}" Header="Action" Width="SizeToHeader" />
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="388,253,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I then created an ActionResult class which uses the INotifyPropertyChanged to update.

```
public class ActionResults : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int _Id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set 
        { 
            _Id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    private string _Action;
    public string Action
    {
        get { return _Action; }
        set 
        { 
            _Action = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Action");
        }
    }
```

and my button in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

My question being from following that tutorial he then creates another class 'ActionResults_' and manually adds records, but as I am using the db table. What do I do from here? please advise I am stuck. Where do the observable collections come into place?

thank you

**EDIT**

```
   private void Load_ActionResult_Table()
    {
        ActionResultsTable.ActionResultDataSet actionResultDataSet = ((ActionResultsTable.ActionResultDataSet)(this.FindResource("actionResultDataSet")));
        // Load data into the table ActionResult. You can modify this code as needed.
        ActionResultsTable.ActionResultDataSetTableAdapters.ActionResultTableAdapter actionResultDataSetActionResultTableAdapter = new ActionResultsTable.ActionResultDataSetTableAdapters.ActionResultTableAdapter();
        actionResultDataSetActionResultTableAdapter.Fill(actionResultDataSet.ActionResult);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource actionResultViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("actionResultViewSource")));
        actionResultViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

  private void Refresh_Table_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //SO DO I NEED TO SAY, SET TABLE TO NULL THEN RELOAD BY USING BELOW FUNCTION?
        Load_ActionResult_Table();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you move the code that reads the data from db to a method, add a call to ObservableCollection.Clear at the beginning and use the method both at application startup and in the button click handler?

Comment: AHH how did I not think of that lol...thanks for the reply markus, worked great. On a different note was I far off from the previous way I was doing it?

Comment: The INotifyPropertyChanged way might also work, but I think the effort would be slightly higher. You'd need to bind the ItemsSource to a collection property just as you do for the ObservanleCollection. Instead of notifying the grid about changes in the collection (which the ObservableCollection does internally), you create a new collection and notify the grid that the property was changed. Also a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose the following, simpler approach:

1. Move the code that reads the data from the database to a separate method.
2. Add a call to ObservableCollection.Clear at the beginning.
3. Call the method at application startup and in the button click event handler.

---

Based upon the edit, the easiest way would be to clear the DataTable before filling it:

```
private void Load_ActionResult_Table()
{
    ActionResultsTable.ActionResultDataSet actionResultDataSet = ((ActionResultsTable.ActionResultDataSet)(this.FindResource("actionResultDataSet")));
    // Load data into the table ActionResult. You can modify this code as needed.
    ActionResultsTable.ActionResultDataSetTableAdapters.ActionResultTableAdapter actionResultDataSetActionResultTableAdapter = new ActionResultsTable.ActionResultDataSetTableAdapters.ActionResultTableAdapter();
    // Clear the table
    actionResultDataSet.ActionResult.Clear();
    actionResultDataSetActionResultTableAdapter.Fill(actionResultDataSet.ActionResult);
    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource actionResultViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("actionResultViewSource")));
    actionResultViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
}
```

Comment: What is the Observable collection is that my db Table? Ive tried actionResultDataGrid.ItemSource = null; Load_ActionResult_Table(); but the null removes it, how can I clear it?

Comment: @John: if you don't have an ObservableCollection up to now, you don't need one. If you bind the grid directly to the table by assigning it to the ItemsSource, just reload the table and assign it to ItemSource again. Am I missing something? Can you show the code that loads the data and binds them to the grid?